# Quick Sort with first element as pivot

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I'm studying Quick-Sort and I am confused as to how it works when the first element is chosen as the pivot point.

I am trying to trace the first step in the Quick-Sort algorithm, to move the pivot S[1] (17) into its appropriate position.

Example: [17, -10, 7, 19, 21, 23, -13, 31, 59].

```
^# = pivot
^ pointer
```

My understanding:

Partition the first part (all elements in this part is less than the pivot).

```
17, -10, 7, 19, 21, 23, -13, 31, 59
^#                               ^
```

Comparison 1. No swap.

```
17, -10, 7, 19, 21, 23, -13, 31, 59
^#                           ^
```

Comparison 2. No swap.

```
17, -10, 7, 19, 21, 23, -13, 31, 59
^#                      ^
```

Comparison 3. Swap.

```
-13, -10, 7, 19, 21, 23, 17, 31, 59
                     ^   ^#
```

Comparison 4. Swap.

```
-13, -10, 7, 19, 21, 17, 23, 31, 59
                 ^   ^#
```

Comparison 5. Swap.

```
-13, -10, 7, 19, 17, 21, 23, 31, 59
             ^   ^#
```

Comparison 6. Swap.

```
-13, -10, 7, 17, 19, 21, 23, 31, 59
          ^  ^#
```

Comparison 7. No swap.

```
 -13, -10, 7, 17, 19, 21, 23, 31, 59
       ^      ^#
```

Comparison 9. No swap.

```
-13, -10, 7, 17, 19, 21, 23, 31, 59
  ^          ^#
```

Comparison 10. No swap.

Is this how it works? Would it take 10 comparisons and 4 swaps to move pivot S[1] (17) into the correct position?

Comment: The sequence depends on the partition algorithm Lomuto, Hoare, or other schemes. Some partition algorithms only move the pivot into the proper partition, but don't put the pivot in it's final sorted position until a certain depth of recursion is reached.

Answer (score 0):

The quick sort will have two moving pointers and one pivot pointer

and the initial positions of these moving pointers will be 0 and n-1 positions (first and last element)
and right point will move towards left looking for a shorter element then pivot once it find that element left pointer start moving to right in search of an element greater than pivot once they find these element they both swap and continue to do the same until both the pointer meet

once they both meet will swap that element with pivot element.

look at the pointer movement for your example below

`17, -10, 7, 19, 21, 23, -13, 31, 59
^#                               ^`

`17, -10, 7, 19, 21, 23, -13, 31, 59
^#                            ^`

`17, -10, 7, 19, 21, 23, -13, 31, 59
^#                        ^`

Right pointer found the -13 < 17 now start moving the left pointer

`17, -10, 7, 19, 21, 23, -13, 31, 59
\#     ^                   ^`

`17, -10, 7, 19, 21, 23, -13, 31, 59
 \#       ^                ^`

`17, -10, 7, 19, 21, 23, -13, 31, 59
\#           ^             ^`

Left point found a value 19 > 17 now swap both the pointer values

`17, -10, 7, -13, 21, 23, 19, 31, 59
\#            ^           ^`

Start moving the right point to find the smaller value then pivot point

`17, -10, 7, -13, 21, 23, 19, 31, 59
\#            ^       ^`

`17, -10, 7, -13, 21, 23, 19, 31, 59
\#            ^   ^`

`17, -10, 7, -13, 21, 23, 19, 31, 59
\#           ^ ^`

`-13, -10, 7, 17, 21, 23, 19, 31, 59
^            \#^`

Comment: The pivot is not always moved into it's sorted position. The quicksort algorithm used in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SLauY6PpjW4) only moves numbers smaller than the pivot to the left of numbers greater than the pivot, and ignores numbers equal to the pivot, including the pivot itself.